# Preserve Selection when Scrolling GXT

Tags: gxt

I am using Sencha GXT Grid for a web app. But what I see is after scrolling the grid the selection is gone. I tried to preserve the selection by catching the scroll event and restoring the selected items (using setsecteditems() ). But was not successful also.
Is there a method to preserve the selection in sencha GXT grid.
Thanx

Comment: What version are you using? Could you post your code too?

Comment: I am using Sencha GXT 3.1.1 the code is same as the code in the LiveGrid example code in GXT samples.
http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:livegrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally able to preserve the selection in Live grid view. I found two ways that I thought worth to share.It's kind of a hack :) 
1. If you are receiving data from a server. You can maintain a boolean in server side data preserving the selection. and when you render rows in the client side you can add a style name to that row checking the boolean which is set previously. 
the style name can be set using

```
 grid.getView().setViewConfig(new GridViewConfig() {

        @Override
        public String getColStyle(Object model, ValueProvider<? super Data, ?> valueProvider, int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getRowStyle(Objectmodel, int rowIndex) {
            //Do the logic here and return the Style name  
            return null;
        }
    });
```

2. You can also maintain a list of keys in client side which contains the selected items. and use the previous method to add a style name if the row you are drawing is in the list.
   Thanx :)